# executing an event after a long time period laravel

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I want to have a subscription mechanism in my app, in a way that after 12 months of subscribing an event would occur that changes their status to unsubscribed, how do I create such a listener for a long time period in laravel?

Comment: sounds like a cronjob would be required, a daily check for expired subscriptions

Comment: You dont create a listener for a long time period. You create a cron job that runs daily and checks the subscription dates for all users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel's task scheduling can handle this.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling

You would be interested in the `->yearly()` method. Add scheduling entries to the `App\Console\Kernel` class.

Example:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    // check subscriptions
})->yearly();
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would save the timestamp in db and second create a cronjob (there is a laravel equivalent) which selects all subscriptions where the timestamp ist older then 12 month.